# remember cookie

Tags: javascript

i want to make a cokkie which can save my selected region on netsoltech.com whenever user select the region on map it can save the cookie and when the next time user come on domain the automatic go to 1st time click region page i make this code
but the problem is when the user come on next time then 1st region selector page come then it can refresh and go to the region page.. not the automatic...

```
<script>
/*
    Cookie script - Scott Andrew
    Popup script, Copyright 2005, Sandeep Gangadharan
*/

function newCookie(name,value,days) {
 var days = 10;   // the number at the left reflects the number of days for the cookie to last
                 // modify it according to your needs
 if (days) {
   var date = new Date();
   date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
   var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString(); }
   else var expires = "";
   document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"; }

function readCookie(name) {
   var nameSG = name + "=";
   var nuller = '';
  if (document.cookie.indexOf(nameSG) == -1)
    return nuller;

   var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
  if (c.indexOf(nameSG) == 0) return c.substring(nameSG.length,c.length); }
    return null; }

function eraseCookie(name) {
  newCookie(name,"",1); }

function toMem(region) {

    newCookie('region', region);    
    window.location= "http://www.netsoltech.com/"+region+"/index";
}


function remCookie() {

window.location= "http://www.netsoltech.com/"+readCookie("region")+"/index";

}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  remCookie();
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;

    //redirect here
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function checkCookie() {
    var region = getCookie("region");
    if (region != null && region != "") {
        alert("redirect to " + region); //replace this with redirect
    }
}

checkCookie();  //check this on page load
```

and the **HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="setCookie('region', 'europe', 365); return false;">europe</a>
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/YtF2B/6/